# Scaled-up SVG has blurry text in Safari

Tags: html, svg, safari

i haven't found a solution to this. i tried many webkit css things.
maybe i used them on the wrong element or they just don't work.

im scaling a SVG with text to 2000vh. my expectation is that an SVG should look fine because its vector based. and my expectations are met in 3/4 browsers.

chrome & firefox & edge(yes indeed):
[image]

safari:
[image]

http://jsfiddle.net/swisswiss/57t4u96z/

```
height: 2200vh;
position: fixed;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is another solution - http://jsfiddle.net/2795fkLb/1/

The main idea that we can increase font-size, and reduce height, top and left.

```
.st2{font-size:88px;}

#Layer_1 {
    height: 550vh;
    top: -250vh;
    left: -250vh;
}
```

In my example, I use 4x. It is still not ideal, but you can increase factor.

Comment: this seems to work. i need to scale it up for responsive design reasons. but 5x vh is maybe enough. i will try this.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using another solution to achieve the same effect (https://codepen.io/IvanBisultanov/pen/WKLoGQ):

```
<div class="result"></div>

.result {
  background-image:url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' version='1.1' height='20px' width='147px'><text x='0' y='15' fill='#000' font-size='20'>REFORMATION</text></svg>");
  background-size: 50vh auto;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

Comment: maybe the fiddle was not clear enough. but im trying to use the SVG as a mask as well and in addition i need to be able to change the SVG text from javascript. thats why i think your solution would only present more problems than it solves

Comment: Better now, I will provide you another way based on your example.